# html: why does height fail with doctype?

Tags: html, html-table, doctype

When I remove the DOCTYPE line this code works the way I want it to.  The "A" link fills the full cell height for the "Cell" cell when hovering over it and clicking anywhere within the cell.  note: I need to use A, and not TD onclick javascript.  I don't understand why adding the DOCTYPE breaks it, or what I can do to fix it properly, and it is driving me nuts.  I'm using IE9, but would like it to work in all browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>X</title>
<style type="text/css">
table,td, th {border: 1px solid #000}
td a {display: block; height:100%; width:100%;}
td a:hover {background-color: yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Cell</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/"><img alt="x" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png"></a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try validating it: http://validator.w3.org/check You have some errors.

Comment: What does "breaking" mean in this case? What do you want it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: breaking = clicking _anywhere_ within the "Cell" cell doesn't work.  (height of A should be 100% to fill the cell) When the DOCTYPE is removed, I can click anywhere within the cell and the link will work, and the hover color is triggered.       It  passes validation now (was missing title).

Comment: Why are you specifying a transitional doctype? Just use <!DOcTYpe HTML> to specify html5.

Comment: It fails with <!DOCTYPE HTML> as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the height of the `<td>` is not defined (it's determined at layout), the `height: 100%;` of its children are ignored.

Set the `height` and `line-height` of the `<td>`:

```css
td { height: 100px; line-height: 100px; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/twVar/

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>X</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table,td, th {border: 1px solid #000}
        td a {display: block; height:100%; width:100%;}
        td a:hover {background-color: yellow;}
        td { height: 100px; line-height: 100px; }
        img { display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">Cell</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><img alt="x" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png"></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: Thank you, that gets me further.  I do not know beforehand a precise line-height for the table row so hard coding 100px isn't possible. I tried line-height: 100%; but then I can't seem to "vertical-align: middle"  the "Cell" text.    I will continue to play with it.

Comment: @JonT The only other option I know of is absolute positioning, but that doesn't play well with tables. You had to set the `<td>` to `relative` and the child to `absolute`.